# The transaction fails when using the SDK, but succeeds when using the REST API

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, sdk, sumup-payments

I have created a checkout order using sumup-ecom-php-sdk.
So I got the checkoutId from the response.

```
$sumup = new \SumUp\SumUp([
  'app_id' => '...',
  'app_secret' => '...',
  'grant_type' => 'client_credentials',
]);

$checkoutService = $sumup->getCheckoutService();
$amount = floatval(str_replace(',', '.', str_replace('.', '', $invoice->total)));
$currency = 'EUR';
$checkoutRef = $invoice->number;
$payToEmail = "dev_igc7qi3x@sumup.com";
$description = 'Test';

$checkoutResponse = $checkoutService->create($amount, $currency, $checkoutRef, $payToEmail, $description);
$checkoutId = $checkoutResponse->getBody()->id;
```

I developed the payment page using the sumup-card widget sdk and loaded the sumup-card using the checkoutId obtained above.

```
@extends('layout.app_layout_client')

@section('body')
    <div id="sumup-card">
    </div>

    <script>
        const checkoutId = @json($checkoutId);

        var sumupCard = SumUpCard.mount({
            checkoutId: checkoutId,
            showAmount: true,
            showFooter: true,
            currency: "EUR",
            locale: "de-DE",
            onResponse: function (type, body) {
                if (type == "success") {
                    console.log(body);
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "/sumup/checkout/complete",
                        type: "PUT",
                        data: {
                            checkoutId: checkoutId,
                        },
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function(res) {
                            if (res.success) {
                                window.location.href = res.redirectUrl;
                            } else {
                                console.log(res.message);
                            }
                        },
                        error: function(error) {
                            console.log("Network Error");
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    console.log(type);
                }
            },
        });
    </script>
@endsection
```

But when I submit the sumup-card form, the transaction always fails.
The result is like the following:

```
{
  "id": "fc0361f0-9689-4eff-89d2-bf138665e494",
  "reference": "23/2352",
  "amount": 119,
  "status": "FAILED",
  "currency": "EUR",
  "description": "Test Checkout",
  "merchant": {
    "code": "..."
  },
  "current_payment": {
    "id": "3510b833-4998-4edd-aeec-ab17780ec5b7",
    "transaction_code": "TCAKA4PQSD",
    "status": "failed",
    "created_at": "2023-04-08T01:33:29+00:00",
    "updated_at": "2023-04-08T01:33:30+00:00"
  }
}
```

On the other hand, if the checkout is handled through the REST API rather than the sumup-card widget, the transaction succeeds.

```
$customService = $sumup->getCustomService();
$customResponse = $customService->request('PUT', '/v0.1/checkouts/'.$checkoutId, [
  "payment_type" => "card",
  "card" => [
     "name" => "Dominik Biermann",
     "number" => "4242424242424242",
     "expiry_month" => "12",
     "expiry_year" => "34",
     "cvv" => "123"
  ]
]);
dd($customResponse);
```

I should implement via SDK. How can I fix it?